# how to start using android-maven-plugin?

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin

First steps to use the android-maven-plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*1* Set android home

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/your/android-SDK/path
```

*2* Run

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=android-with-test 
-DarchetypeGroupId=de.akquinet.android.archetypes -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.9 
-DgroupId=org.me -DartifactId=myAndroidApp -Dplatform=8
```

[Here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg:%22de.akquinet.android.archetypes%22)  To check the archetypeVersion or look for other ones.

*3*

Edit myAndroidApp/pom.xml (parent level pom.xml) to set (it is initially void)

```
<platform.version> 2.2.1 </platform.version>
```

in the properties section. Please make sure the correspondence
between platform 8 and platform.version 2.2.1
You can learn in your android sdk manager app that API 8 <-> 2.2,
but must visit [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg:%22com.google.android%22%20AND%20a:%22android%22) to see that the final number is 2.2.1.
(Note: for API 10 <-> 2.3.3).

*4*

You can start right now to play with it. In the parent directory:

```
mvn clean install
```

and to run it (in myAndroidApp/myAndroidApp directory)

```
cd myAndroidApp
mvn android:run
```

Be sure you started a phone emulator or attached a real phone (in debug mode)
to your computer.

Hope this saves you a whole weekend! (Too late for me ;-) )

Comment: Just keep in mind that the archetype is out of date at this stage. Might be better to replicated and adopt one of the example projects: http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/examples.html