# How to install android-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-maven-plugin

I need to use the **`android-maven-plugin`** for my project (especially for the multidex feature) but I can not figure out how to configure my actual `pom.xml` file (is is a standard file). I am using Eclipse Luna on Windows.

I did not manage to find any tutorial, does anyone has a good link about how to use and configure it ?

I want to use this plugin artifact :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
</plugin>
```

NOTE : do not confund with groupId `com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2`

NOTE 2 : I think it is not the same problem and solution here : [how to start using android-maven-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441841/how-to-start-using-android-maven-plugin)

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBuildMaven/article.html

Comment: you should stop using Eclipse for Android development. It's officially not supported anymore, and you will always get into more and more trouble trying to use it.

Comment: @Budius Thank you for the advice. But my project is mainly a desktop application and the android part is small... so I do not want to use Android Studio for the whole project, I could use both in the same time but I can feel in advance that it will be a nightmare :-/ And also I do not want to migrate the whole project on Gradle, I do not have time for this.

Comment: @ask4solutions Thank you but the tutorial is for the groupId that I say I did not want to use...

Answer (score 1):

The Android Maven Plugin used to use the jayway groupId and has simply migrated to the simpligility based one.

All instructions you find are still valid apart from the differing groupId. Specifically I would suggest to look at the [documentation website](http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/) and the [example projects](http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/examples.html).

Comment: Hi Manfred, since ADT for Eclipse is not compatible with multidex I decided to migrate to Android Studio :-/ Thank you anyway

Comment: ADT is maintained as part of the Eclipse Andmore project and they are probably going to support multidex (or maybe do so already).

Comment: And my answer still applies so maybe you want to accept it.

Comment: In fact I was hoping for a tutorial more than a technical documentation. I think a kind of "how to install plugin" for the noob would help some people (like I did here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/maven-android-developers/QzFg158CMww/Z3G3ZveHIKoJ)